# Javascript how to assign global objects to variables inside classes?

Tags: javascript

`window.foo` is a global object.
If I console.log(window.foo), it shows that exists.
I want to make a class to hold that objects, like so

```
class Globals {
   static foo = window.foo;
}
```

but if I console.log(Globals.foo), it says undefined. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is it `window.foo` or `window.food`?

Comment: Where is the global `foo` variable defined? Does it happen before the class is created?

Comment: @Bergi it is window.foo, sorry I fixed it. I'm writing an extension for a website, so window.foo is a global object of the original website, I think the problem is when my injected JS runs, foo is not yet declared by the original website, so it was assigned undefined. And when I specifically do console.log(window.foo) it works because by that time window.foo has been declared. Do you know how I can create the class after the website has declared window.foo?

Comment: That depends on how the website declares `window.foo` (and how the script that does it is loaded).

Comment: @Bergi Okay thanks. I'm using setTimeout to delay loading my script as a temporary solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want a global object to hold things, you were already half way there, simply define `window.Globals = {}`.

```
window.Globals = {
    foo: window.foo
}
```

Comment: If the `class` doesn't work, this hardly will either.

Comment: Well, it didn't work because he was never creating an instance of the class, that and the typescript syntax. The question is too ambiguous as to presume what he wants to do with it, however.

Comment: If the question is too ambiguous, you shouldn't post an answer :-)

Comment: That's fair! ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing:

```
class Globals{
    constructor(){
        this.foo = window.foo;
    }

}
```

The definition you're using for `static foo` is typescript, not javascript :)

While doing the above process would be good enough for your usage, another way is to use constructors:

```
class Globals{
    constructor(foo){
        this.foo = foo;
    }

}

const globals = new Globals(window.foo);
```

Comment: `class Globals {
    this.foo = window.foo;
}` is a syntax error

Comment: @Bergi, true, missed the constructor in the above line